# How to get access Object from API response?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I want to access Object with data from API response.

Presently, the response in the console looks like this:
[image]

But I want to get this data:
[image]

**This is browser script. Not NODE**

My entire code...

```
const input = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');

function getData(symbol) {
  return fetch(
    `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/` +
      `https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/fundamentals/${symbol}?api_token=***************`,
    {
      method: "get",
    }
  )
    .then((data) => {
      if (!data.ok) {
        throw new Error("Symbol is 'empty'");
      }
      (data) => data.json();
      console.log(data);
      return data;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      throw error;
    });
}

input.addEventListener(
  "change",
  function (e) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = async function () {
      const symbolsArr = reader.result.split("\n").map((str) => str.trim());
      let json_file = await getData(symbolsArr[0]);
      saveFile(json_file, "json.txt", "text/plain");
      symbolsArr.forEach((element) => {});
    };
    reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
  },
  false
);
function saveFile(content, fileName, contentType) {
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  var file = new Blob([content], { type: contentType });
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  a.download = fileName;
  a.click();
}
```

I want to save the Object from the response to a `json_file` variable and then execute the `saveFile` method to save the file locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is returned from an API inside the body attribute of the response. Try printing

```
data.body
```

to the console.

Finally once the JSON is received, use the stringify function to parse the JSON into a string and then store it in the file.

```
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Comment: Now console is printing what i wanted but in saved file is only "[Object object]". How i should parse that .json to .txt file?

Comment: Try using the stringify function. ```var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);```